# PHP code hanging in browser when trying to POST to mysql DB (at different random intervals)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have an HTML project using javascript + jquery which is Posting data froma table to MySQL via PHP.

My Table looks like this:

[image]

The array "Results" looks like:

[image]

My jquery code:

```
function save(results) {
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object

        results = results.chunk(11)

        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file

            vars ="event=" + results[i][0] + "&swimmername=" + results[i][1] + "&lane=" + results[i][2] + "&time=" + results[i][3] + "&place=" + results[i][4] + "&scoreA=" + results[i][5] + "&scoreB=" + results[i][6] + "&lane2=" + results[i][7] + "&time2=" + results[i][8] + "&place2=" + results[i][9] + "&swimmername2=" + results[i][10];
            //var vars = "event="+eventName+"&swimmername="+swimmerName+"&lane="+swimmerLane+"&time="+swimmerTime+"&place="+swimmerPlace+"&scoreA="+teamAScore+"&scoreB="+teamBScore+"&lane2="+swimmerLane2+"&time2="+swimmerTime2+"&place2="+swimmerPlace2+"&swimmername2="+swimmerName2;
            $.ajax({
                url: "save.php",
                type: "POST",

                data: vars,

                success: function (data) {
                    results.length = 0;
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = data;

                },

                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Status: " + textStatus);
                    alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
                }



            });
        }
```

My PHP Save.php

```
<?php

$connection = db_connect();

if(isset($_POST['swimmername'])){$name =  $_POST['swimmername'];}
if(isset($_POST['lane'])){$lane = $_POST['lane'];}
if(isset($_POST['place'])){$place = $_POST['place'];}
if(isset($_POST['time'])){$time = $_POST['time'];}
if(isset($_POST['scoreA'])){$score = $_POST['scoreA'];}
if(isset($_POST['scoreB'])){$score2 = $_POST['scoreB'];}
if(isset($_POST['time2'])){$time2 = $_POST['time2'];}
if(isset($_POST['lane2'])){$lane2 = $_POST['lane2'];}
if(isset($_POST['place2'])){$place2 = $_POST['place2'];}
if(isset($_POST['swimmername2'])){$name2 =  $_POST['swimmername2'];}
if(isset($_POST['event'])){$event =  $_POST['event'];}
var_dump($event);
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT eventName FROM hs_swim.swimMeetData where eventName ='$event'");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($event !="")
{
    if($num_rows<3)
    {

        $query = "INSERT INTO swimMeetData SET eventName='$event', swimmer_name='$name',lane='$lane',place='$place', time='$time', score='$score', scoreB='$score2', timeB='$time2', placeB='$place2',laneB='$lane2',swimmer_nameB='$name2' ";

        if ($connection->query($query) === TRUE) {
            echo ($event +" record created successfully");
            mysqli_close($connection);
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo ($event +" record already Exists");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Houston,,We have a problem ";

}

function db_connect() {
    $servername = "127.0.0.1";
    $username = "swimmer";
    $password = "swimmer";
    $dbname = "hs_swim";

    // Define connection as a static variable, to avoid connecting more than once
    static $connection;

    // Try and connect to the database, if a connection has not been established yet
    if(!isset($connection)) {
        // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file

        $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    }

    // If connection was not successful, handle the error
    if($connection === false) {
        // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
        return mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    return $connection;
}

?>
```

When I click on "SUBMIT" works well and updates the Database until I suddenly get:
NULL values for event when after debugging, I definitely have that value selected.

[image]

The Network details show:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: There are so so sooooo many problems with that code. But focusing on your question, the problem does not seem to be in the part of the code you sent (or maybe it is related with not encoding your spaces?). How do you bind the event on the button? Also... u pressed submit multiple times without waiting to finish the request (seems so from your print).

Comment: Hi Zozo,

When I click submit, it is bound to a "click" event that will gather the data from the table and then save it via the PHP

The Submission works fine for the first few times and the DB gets updated fine, but suddenly it starts "pending" and locks up and sends the "NULL"

Comment: So the event is added dynamically... is it possible you bind it twice? And one of them is not bound right (reads from somewhere else or something)?

Comment: The button is added when I slidetoggle the Table row.
The event is static



    $(".submitRow").click(function () {

        getScore()
        getTableData();
        $(".editRow").css("display", "inline")
        $('th#eventNames').attr("disabled", "disabled");

    });

Comment: What are the problems with the code? The JS or PHP?

Comment: One min, I create a chat room :) -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94833/php-code-hanging-in-browser-when-trying-to-post-to-mysql-db-at-different-random

Comment: Reenter and try now, I voted up so you get the rep

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94834/discussion-between-user5451365-and-zozo).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['event'])){$event =  $_POST['event'];}
```

to:

```
$event = isset($_POST['event']) ? $_POST['event'] : '';
```

Comment: That would solve the problem, but not its root. He will end up with blank events.

Comment: Still not letting me chat... shoot